# Impedance value effect on voltage measurement

Tags: voltage, adc, impedance, input

When I measure voltage of, for instance, the open circuit voltage at low luminous intensity of a photodetector with ADC Adruino Uno an offset appears. The value is good if the photodecteor (here an LED used as receiver) is illuminated.  Is it an effect of the high input impedance value of the ADC input?
..........
I think also that the input bias currents through the high input
impedance value make this offset, the same problem like a non connected input.
MP

Comment: You probably have 0 offset issue and need to offset/amplify your input with an opamp

Comment: Input bias currents.

Comment: LED as photodetector? These become *very high impedance* at low light levels. ADC input impedance is a small capacitor fed by a series resistor. At low light levels, leakage currents have a large influence on the ADC result. Temperature too. You should be aware too that the LED voltage response to light is logarithmic, not linear.

Comment: @glen_geekThanks , yes  this is probably the reason. We want to use Voltage Open Circuit voltage  response because the logarithmic behaviour with incident light.